# C++ Rounding float-pointing value to number of fractional digits

Tags: c++, rounding, digits

I have tried std::round but it doesn't give me result that I want exactly. So my question is I have program in C# and I am converting to C++ and I faced with this problem. C# Math.round and C++ round are different. So this causes wrong calculations.
C# code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.850, 1));
```

Output:

```
0,8
```

C++ code:

```
 std::cout << roundf(0.850f) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
1
```

So like you see they are different. How can I solve this ?

Comment: In C++, the function `roundf()` rounds toward zero.   That is completely different from what the C# `Math.Round` function does.   You can't assume that two functions in different programming languages do the same thing, just because their names are similar.   Try reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# version is rounding a `double` to one decimal place, the C++ version is rounding a `float` to the nearest integer.

Rounding a binary floating point to a fixed number of decimal places doesn't really make much sense, as the rounded number will still most likely be an approximation. For example `0.8` cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point.

The C++ round function only rounds to the nearest integral value, which, given the above, is a sensible choice.

You can recover the C# behaviour (rounding to 1 decimal place) with `std::round(0.850 * 10) / 10`.

Note that I've dropped the `f` suffix to match the C# `double` type.